# Best way to toggle radio input and call a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with radio buttons, and I'd like to show/hide a div when people click each of the radio options. The code below works per se, but it's buggy, ie: it'll work if I hard refresh the page, but other times it will only show/hide the div but it won't toggle between the radio inputs. I usually call this function inside a  but this is the first I'm trying to have it called when a user clicks on a form element. Is there a better way of calling the function so that it will always work as expected?

```
<label class="rcontainer" onmousedown="toggleSlide('taxagentdet');" id="ag1">No
  <input id="form18" type="radio" name="TaxAgent" value="0">
  <span class="rbutton"></span>
</label>
<label class="rcontainer" onmousedown="toggleSlide('taxagentdet');" id="ag2">Yes
  <input id="form19" type="radio" name="TaxAgent" value="1">
  <span class="rbutton"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What does `toggleSlide()` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function toggleDiv(toggleType) {
const el = document.getElementById("div_content");
    if(toggleType === 'yes')  el.style.display="block";
  if(toggleType === 'no')  el.style.display="none";
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" onChange="toggleDiv('yes')" name="Yes" id="yes" checked="true"> <label for="yes" >YES</label>
<input type="radio" onChange="toggleDiv('no')" name="Yes" id="no"> <label for="no">NO</label>

<div id="div_content">
DIV Content
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect, thank you! I made a small change and put the onChange inside my <label> tag: `code`<label class="rcontainer" onChange="toggleDiv('no')" id="no">No
  <input id="form18" type="radio" name="TaxAgent" value="0">`code` - it seems to still function fine but will be creating any problems by doing this? Should I still expect that to work across browsers & devices etc?

Comment: @CraigWalters it will work fine, I think this answer helped you, so mark it as your answer.(Click the grey tick and change to green)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR. Use the built-in HTML structure as much as possible

See the sample code snippet below. In it, `form` element wraps two radio `input` elements of the same name, and you can use JavaScript to listen for its `change` event rather than detecting individual `mousedown`. This will also enable users to use keyboard to toggle between radios.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const div = document.querySelector('.content');

form.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // Do whatever you need to do to toggle
  const toggleStatus = e.target.value === "yes" ? "Toggle On" : "Toggle Off";
  div.innerText = toggleStatus;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="no"><input type="radio" id="no" name="toggle" value="no">No</label>
  <label for="yes"><input type="radio" id="yes" name="toggle" value="yes">Yes</label>
</form>
<div class="content" style="padding: 20px; margin-top: 20px; box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2); width: 150px;">
  Unselected
</div>
```